# Sublime Text 3 Can't Find File

Tags: lua, sublimetext3, sublimetext

test code:

```
print(1);
```

build:

```
{
       "cmd": "lua", "$file",
       "file_regex": "^lua: (...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.lua"
 }
```

output:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['luajit', 'C:\\Users\\phill\\Desktop\\test.lua']]
[dir: C:\Users\phill\Desktop]
[path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1"]
[Finished]
```

It won't build the file because, it can't find it.

Comment: I can use lua in CMD btw

Comment: Did you save the file and then run the build system? And why does your build system say `lua` while the error message says `luajit`?

Comment: Do you really have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luajit.exe` ?

Comment: Sorry, I selected the wrong build sys. I still get the same output even if it uses 'lua' as the command in the output.